# Confidence Intervals for ratio of risk ratios

Tags: confidence-interval, ratio

How can you compute the confidence intervals for a ratio of risk ratios? For example:
RRa = 0.52 (95% CI 0.25 to 1.08)
RRb = 0.68 (95% CI 0.52 to 0.89)

If I take the natural logarithm of each RR (RRa = -0.65, RRb = -0.39), then my ratio is 0.39/0.65 = 0.6

But I don't have confidence intervals for this number (0.6)...

Assume I don't have the raw data used to develop the original risk ratios

Answer (score 1):

Shortly before he died, John Pezzullo wrote an Excel spreadsheet that calculates the ratio and confidence interval (and p value) for a comparison of either [1](http://statpages.info/Confidence%20Intervals%20to%20P-values.xlsx) two ratios and their confidence intervals or [2](http://statpages.info/Converting%20confidence%20intervals%20to%20p%20values.pdf) two means and their confidence intervals.

The Excel spreadsheet (with one tab for means and another for ratios) is [here](http://statpages.info/Confidence%20Intervals%20to%20P-values.xlsx).

With an explanation [here](http://statpages.info/Converting%20confidence%20intervals%20to%20p%20values.pdf).

For the example in the question, using the Ratios tab in the Excel spreadsheet for 0.52 (95% CI 0.25 to 1.08) compared to 0.68 (95% CI 0.52 to 0.89) we get 0.76 (0.35-1.67) for A/B and 1.31 (0.60-2.85) for B/A, with p = 0.50.

Comment: Thanks. Any formulas and citations behind the John Pezzullo's spreadsheet?