# Likelihood-Based Confidence Intervals for ratio of risk ratios

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, likelihood, relative-risk

> Ratio of Risk Ratio (RRR), along with Relative Excess Risk Due to
>   Interaction (RERI), has been used to quantify the joint effects of 2
>   exposures in epidemiology.

Quoting [Joshua N. Pritikin](https://europepmc.org/backend/ptpmcrender.fcgi?accid=PMC5863926&blobtype=pdf)

> CIs based on standard errors (SEs) are common in practice, but
>   likelihood-based CIs are worth consideration. In comparison to SEs,
>   likelihood-based CIs are typically more difficult to estimate, but are
>   more robust to model (re)parameterization.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277274/confidence-intervals-for-ratio-of-risk-ratios?rq=1) shows how confidence intervals for the ratio of ratios can be calculated using standard error "[when the data can be considered at least approximately normally distributed](http://statpages.info/Converting%20confidence%20intervals%20to%20p%20values.pdf)."

Given the example dataset from [Nie et al, 2010](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20502336):

[image]

The ratio of RR for A in strata of B can be calculated using:

$RRR(A) = RR(B=1)/RR(B=0)$

**My questions are:**

> 1. How can I implement in practice in R the estimation of likelihood-based confidence intervals for the RRR above?
> 2. Is there a simpler alternative (e.g., bootstrap approaches, delta method) that is robust even when the data cannot " [be considered ...approximately normally distributed](http://statpages.info/Converting%20confidence%20intervals%20to%20p%20values.pdf)" and could be easy to implement in R to derive CI for RRR above?

Comment: R code questions are off-topic here strictly speaking but for your Q1, does it not work to fit a log-binomial model and then use confint() on the fitted model?